# Error The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened while updating

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I was trying to :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Didn't work with error:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://ftp.hu.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:5 https://quantum-mirror.hu/mirrors/pub/mx-linux/packages/antix/buster buster InRelease
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'fore+gn' for package 'nxproxy'
Problem parsing dependency 21
Error occurred while processing nxproxy (NewVersion2)
Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists         /ftp.hu.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_main_binary-amd64_Packages
The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
Can't call method "policy" on an undefined value at /usr/bin/apt-show-versions line 53.
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-  versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'fore+gn' for package 'nxproxy'
E: Problem parsing dependency 21
E: Error occurred while processing nxproxy (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.hu.debian.org_debian_dists_buster_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: This question belong to [Unix&Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To fix MergeList problem:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```